# Only one image shows up when i load a list of images

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am writing a tower defense game, and I need to place a list of JPanels with Buffered images loaded onto them onto a JFrame. I am using a for loop to place the JPanels onto the JFrame, however, when I run the program, only the last JPanel in the list shows up. I have checked to make sure that the images aren't being placed onto one another, and they are being placed in three separate locations.

here is the code for my class which creates a JFrame:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;    

public class GameScreen extends JPanel 
                    implements MouseListener {

    private ArrayList< JPanel > images;
    private TDGame currentGame;
    private JFrame frame;
    private static final int width = 700;
    private static final int length = 700;

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        this.repaint();
    }
    
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        this.repaint();
    }
    
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        this.repaint();
    }
    
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        this.repaint();
    }
    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        this.repaint();
    }
    
    public GameScreen() {
        super();
        images = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
        currentGame = new TDGame();
        frame = new JFrame("Tower Defense");
        frame.setSize(width, length);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
        frame.getContentPane().add(this,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        currentGame.EnemyForce.add(currentGame.EnemyForce.size(),
                                new BasicEnemy(0, 0, LoadImage()));
        currentGame.EnemyForce.add(currentGame.EnemyForce.size(),
                                new BasicEnemy(250, 250, LoadImage2()));
        currentGame.EnemyForce.add(currentGame.EnemyForce.size(),
                                new BasicEnemy(0, 0, LoadImage1()));

        this.repaint();
    }

    public BufferedImage LoadImage() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("Saturn-Intruder.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return img;
    }
    
    public BufferedImage LoadImage1() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("Level1-TD.jpeg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return img;
    }
    
    public BufferedImage LoadImage2() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("BlackBird-Intruder.jpeg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        return img;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        for(int i = 0; i < currentGame.Defense.size(); i++) {
            frame.add(currentGame.Defense.get(i));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < currentGame.EnemyForce.size(); i++) {
            frame.add( currentGame.EnemyForce.get(i));
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < currentGame.ShotsFired.size(); i++) {
            frame.add(currentGame.ShotsFired.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for the JPanels being placed onto the JFrame:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class BasicEnemy extends Entity {
    JPanel ePanel;
    Graphics g;

    public BasicEnemy(double x, double y, BufferedImage image) {
        super(x, y, image);
        ePanel = new JPanel();
        ePanel.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(getImage(), (int)(getXCoord()),
                            (int)(getYCoord()), null);
    }
}
```

How could I fix this problem so that all the images are being placed, not only one?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2) A single blank line of white space in source code is *always* enough.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant. 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently. 4) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: 1) Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`. 2) By the time of deployment, those resources will likely become an [tag:embedded-resource].  That being the case, the resource must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.  3)  **Don't go adding components within the `paintComponent(..)` method**  That in itself will trigger a `repaint()` and infinite loop. 4) When painting images, use the `ImageObserver` instead of `null`.

Comment: In fact, the more I look at that source, the more I think you should toss it and start out fresh, with new learning sources.  It is beyond salvageable.

Comment: Even though you shouldn't be adding components in your paint method, adding any more components is simply placing them in the centre position of the border layout, meaning that only the last component added will, be visible

Answer (score 1):

I dont know exactly why your game is only showing one image. But as going further with this game I would highly recommend you move away from adding each image in its own JPanel.

What I would do with your source code that would make it work.

- Remove the JPanel from the BasicEnemy (and all other classes like that)
- Change all those for loops inside GameScreen.paintComponent to read

  for(...) { currentGame.EnemyForce.get(i).paintComponent(g); }
- in your constructor for GameScreen add `frame.add(this);` right before `frame.setVisible(true);`

If your going to use graphics with Swing you should never hold individual elements that are part of the game inside JCompondents. You should use your GameScreen as your "canvas" and inside paintComponent use the Graphics object to paint all your game stuff.